# Keyboard shortcuts for Terminal

Tags: terminal, shortcut, system-settings

I am trying to add a shortcut to the menu bar actions in the Terminal app, (specifically to create a new window with my own theme.) Here is a screenshot:

[image: Here is a screenshot]

However when I try to add the shortcut via the System Preferences Keyboard Shortcuts page,

[image]

the Terminal app does not show up as one of the options for apps that could have more shortcuts. I looked in the "Other..." section of apps for Terminal, but Terminal was grayed out and unelectable:

[image]
Is this even possible, to add a shortcut to the menu bar in the Terminal app, and if so, how would it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add `Presentation` to you keyboard shortcuts list in `System Preferences` and that should work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the dropdown to choose an app, there should be an Other... option (this is for apps that are not listed).

[image: The Other option]

From there you should be able to just type "Presentation" into the dialog, because that is the first occurrence in the Terminal menu.

Comment: I tried this, and searched for Terminal, but it was grayed out and unselectable.

Comment: In `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`? That's really odd...

Comment: Yes. I added another screenshot to the question.